# How do I print a board like this in python?

Tags: python, arrays

desired output:
[image: desired output]

I'm trying to print a board that looks like this using 2d arrays but im stuck. this is the code I have so far.

```
blank = ' ' 
board = [[ blank ] * 20 for i in range(19) ] 
def printboard(board):
  for i in board:
       for j in i:
           print(j, end = '')
       print('|')
printboard(board)
```

Comment: Please add the desired  output to the question directly, rather than linking to an image.

Comment: Is there a limitation on what you're allowed to do? Can you just print out the actual text for the board using [triple quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)?

Comment: What exactly is it you are stuck with?

Comment: You go through a lot of work for the output you generate.  Your function merely prints the input board, one character at a time, and appends a `|` to the end of each line.  Your input is a blank board.  I see no attempt to print the top and bottom digits, and no attempt to add the line numbering.

Comment: Quit trying to do it all at once; your programming skills aren't there ... yet.  Write a loop to print one line at a time.  Then add leading and trailing vertical bars.  Then add line numbers.  Do this all one step at a time, rather than jumping into the deep end of the data pool.

Answer (score 3):

I think the input to your function should be the length of your desired box. Then you can pass `n=20` to the following function to get the result

```
 def printboard(n):
    print(' ' + ''.join([str(i % 10) for i in list(range(n))]))
    print(' ' + ''.join(['_']*n))
    for i in range(n):
        print('|' + ' '*n + '|' + str(i))
    print(' ' + ''.join(['_']*n))
    print(' ' + ''.join([str(i % 10) for i in list(range(n))]))
```